# Typescript Inference in VSCode not working?

Tags: typescript

[image: example of inference not working]

In the above, you can see that the `Settings` variable knows, on some level, its type inference. It shows it right there. Why do I now need to copy that line and declare it's type?

Is this intended or have I got something incorrectly set in my tsconfig/tslint file?

Comment: It's a `tslint` error, and doesn't appear to involve `typescript` itself: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/typedef/. You could disable the rule in your `tslint.json` file, or check that your `connect` function has a declared type.